# Is it bad to do fake inheritance for a classes attribute

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, pyqt, pyside

First off this question is based around PySide, but it is a general question of inheritance for class attributes.

So I have an inheritance problem. I basically want to inherit from 2 PySide GUI classes. Multiple inheritance had major conflicts and gave errors. Basically, I made a custom widget and want to make that same widget into a dock widget (floating window).

One way that I found easy to implement was to override the **getattr** method to redirect attribute calls, like below.

```
class DockWidget(QtGui.QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.test = Test()

        # Container is a custom widget containing the Test widget and a toolbar.
        self.setWidget(self.test.getCustomContainer())

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        """Call a property's method when the given attribute name is not found.

        Note: Gives full access to the test attribute.

        Args:
            name (str): Method or property name.
        """
        if hasattr(self.test, name):
            return self.test.__getattribute__(name)
    # end __getattr
# end class DockWidget

class Test(QtGui.QWidget):
    def doSomething(self, msg):
        print(msg)
    # end doSomething
# end Test

widg = DockWidget()
widg.doSomething("Test")
```

I would like to know if this is considered really bad, and if there is a better way.

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the two classes together should do? This sounds either like you need a "has a" or a very different design pattern to get to the functionality you want.

Comment: The regular widget "Test" just operates on some data and displays it. I want someone to be able to use "Test" just like it would normally be used only as a dock widget instead. Typically, "Test" is paired with a toolbar and another item in a display widget, so I want the whole display in a dock widget while still calling the methods from "Test". I just don't want to have stored references of "Test" all over my code and have them handled in the dock widget. It is easier to keep track of a dock widget then both classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `DockWidget` and `Test` both inherit `QWidget`, you can use a mixin. This would allow you to do things like reimplement virtual methods, which would not be possible using `__getattr__`.

```
class WidgetMixin(object):
    def doSomething(self, msg):
        print(msg)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        print(self.__class__.__name__)

class Test(WidgetMixin, QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class DockWidget(WidgetMixin, QtGui.QDockWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

Comment: Thanks! It my main class was actually a QPlainTextEdit, so I had to put everything in a QWidget first. After I changed the QWidget to set the layout I was able to have the QDockWidget inherit the QWidget and everything worked!